# django - loop and retrieve unique objects from queryset

Tags: django

I have this code:

```
{% for book in library.history_books.all %}

{% endfor %}
```

`history_books` is the `related_name` in HistoryBooks Model.

now, there can be books with same name. I want to get only unique books - meaning, i want to show only books with different names from each other. e.g. instead of `BookA,BookA`, i show only `BookA`.

How can i do this in template side? I am rendering only libraries to template, so it would be cool to able to do this in template

Comment: Try `library.history_books.distinct`.

Comment: @Rohan, thanks, but is it also possible to distinct by name?

Comment: If you have postgress db, but even in that you can't pass parameter to a method in template. Do you have 2 rows with same book name?

Comment: @Rohan, yeah. i have 2 book entries with same name. But i think, it is better to prohibit this, right?

Comment: That will be much cleaner.

Comment: @Rohan, thanks man. i will do it then..